# Trunk in a tree

Tags: elementary-set-theory, trees

Just to make things clear:
the author defines a **trunk** of a tree by formula in [...] in $4.3.1(a)$ in the snippet below.
Is it true that since $\eta_0\in T$ is maximal then for all $\nu\in T$ it holds **vacuously** that
$lg(\nu)\leq lg(\eta_0)$ ?

[image]

Comment: I think that it does not hold vacuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the definition allows $\nu\in T$ with $\operatorname{\ell g}(\nu)>\operatorname{\ell g}(\eta_0)$. It imposes just two requirements on them:

- $\nu\upharpoonright\operatorname{\ell g}(\eta_0)=\eta_0$, since $\operatorname{\ell g}\big(\nu\upharpoonright\operatorname{\ell g}(\eta_0)\big)\le\operatorname{\ell g}(\eta_0)$; and
- there is a $\mu\in T$ such that $\operatorname{\ell g}(\mu)\le\operatorname{\ell g}(\nu)$, and $\mu\ne\nu\upharpoonright\operatorname{\ell g}(\mu)$.

The first follows from the fact that $\eta_0$ is the trunk of $T$, and the second follows from the fact that $\nu$ is longer than the trunk.

The terminology really is descriptive: every sequence in $T$ that is no longer than $\eta_0$ is an initial segment of $\eta_0$, and every longer sequence in $T$ has $\eta_0$ as an initial segment. All of the branching occurs above $\eta_0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "it" in "it imposes" ? Also, there is unbalanced number of parenthesis in you first bullet. Could you add ")" ?

Comment: @user122424: *It* in the first two sentences refers to the definition of *trunk*; I’ll make that clearer.